# pros & cons new setup

Tags: hard-drive, setup

all; would like some input on a new system build:

Mobo: [Gigabyte x570 gaming x](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X570-GAMING-X-rev-10/support#dl)
RAM: 32 GB  (2x16)
SSD: 500 GB M2.0 (O/s drive)
HDD: 3 ea. 2 TB WD Reds.

my question is, would I benefit from striping through windows 2 of the reds for working files and use the 3rd 2Tb as internal B/up? was origialy going to setup ssd m2.0 as O/s and use on-board raid to set up raid 5 3 drive setup but using on-board raid seems to disable m2.0 drive. all input will be welcome.

Comment: Internal backups are perilously risky. Fire? Theft? Nephew toddler using your optical drive as a toaster slot? Grandpa using your ODD caddy as a cupholder? Backups should be outside the chassis. Add a H/W RAID controller for RAID5 and be pleased with the speed enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I use both internal and external backups. The local back up is day to day on going while my external is big picture.

The internal is to capture smaller things like recovering a version of a file that saved yesterday and did something stupid to today.

The external backup is for not losing everything if one of the events KYAAY notes occurs, as well as physical theft of your entire system.

My understanding is that RAID is a thing of the past now partly because it has some serious downsides such as your data is NOT PROTECTED while recovering from a disk failure.

A couple of articles why not to use RAID as backup

[Article 1](https://blog.storagecraft.com/5-reasons-raid-not-backup/)

[Article 2](http://www.petemarovichimages.com/2013/11/24/never-use-a-raid-as-your-backup-system/)